# Fix a Dataframe on left and fill the other in between on the right with respect to a common column by sorting

Tags: pandas

I have  2 DFs

**DF1:**

```
S.NO Let    No
1    A      10
2    B      20
3    C      80
4    D     100
5    F      8
6    G      9
```

**DF2:**

```
Name    Gam1    Gam2    No
Hu       Ar      Yz     25
gy       Get     Tr     7
ga       Gy      Gy     90
```

I want to fix the DF1 and fill the Df2 on the right in between with respect to the values in No column like this

```
  S.No Let No  Name Gam1 Gam2
    1   A   10          
    2   B   20          
            25  Hu    Ar    Yz
    3   C   80          
            90  ga    Gy    Gy
    4   D   100         
            7   gy    Get   Tr
    5   F   8           
    6   G   9
```

i tried sort like this after merging these 2 Dfs

```
new.sort_values(by=['No'])
```

and the output is coming as below

```
S.NO    Let No  Name    Gam1    Gam2
1       A   10          
2       B   20          
3       C   80          
4       D   100         
5       F   8           
6       G   9           
            25  Hu       Ar      Yz
            7   gy       Get    Tr
            90  ga        Gy    Gy
```

How can i fix this

Comment: Try this `new.sort_values('No')`

Comment: That is sorting the DF1 as well :(

Comment: Why do want to avoid that?

Comment: DF1 should be fixed and DF2 should go in between DF1

Comment: How about if you sorted the data frames separately by 'No' before merging them?

Comment: i dont get you, i want them to be merged and sorted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171613/discussion-between-letroot-and-python-newbie).